# How to append element in empty section?

Tags: jquery

I want to append one `li` element to empty element

```
$().append('<li></li>')
```

But it's not working.

Comment: How should looks _empty tag_? You probably wanted to append to `$(document)`.

Comment: Empty Tag Means ?? Whats is the name of that Empty Tag ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no empty tag, you mean `document`.

```
$(document).append('<li></li>');
```

Comment: How does this be correct? This will create invalid html right?

Comment: I have one for loop there I need to construct one li and then have to add list in dom. But for constructing the list I need some base element where I can add or append constructed elements via loop. So I took $() as base element and calling $().append('<li></li>') from inside loop. But it's not working.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi: yes, it will be invalid (doesn't matter), but i works and seems like valid list - https://jsfiddle.net/yj5h5hu2/. It doesn't matter if we append `<p>` or `<li>`, the JS part stays the same. In webdevelopment there are two groups of people. One is strictly for valid websites, the second one for usability. I prefer the second way.

Answer (score 0):

Therefore try this...

```
<ul id="test">
<!-- append li's here -->
</ul>

$("#test").append('<li></li>');
```